# MongoDB findOne query returns null for some keys

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

[image: MongoShell snippet]

Few queries in my database(`heartbeat`) are returning null, even though those values exists in the document.
In this case as you can see in the image rows with Age 37 exists but query returns null for both number and string type. but other query returns correct result. Indexing doesn't exist on any keys except `_id`.
Below is the code snippet of the above image.

```
> db.heartbeat.find({}).limit(2)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("616d93fdadc1f5af9f25aeb5"), "Age" : "63", "Sex" : "1", "ChestPainType" : "3", "RestingBP" : "145", "Cholesterol" : "233", "FastingBloodSugar" : "1", "RestingECG" : "0", "MaxHeartRate" : "150", "ExerciseInducedAngina" : "0", "STDepression" : "2.3", "STlope" : "0", "ca" : "0", "thal" : "1", "target" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("616d93fdadc1f5af9f25aeb6"), "Age" : "37", "Sex" : "1", "ChestPainType" : "2", "RestingBP" : "130", "Cholesterol" : "250", "FastingBloodSugar" : "0", "RestingECG" : "1", "MaxHeartRate" : "187", "ExerciseInducedAngina" : "0", "STDepression" : "3.5", "STlope" : "0", "ca" : "0", "thal" : "2", "target" : "1" }
> db.heartbeat.findOne({"Age": 37})
null
> db.heartbeat.findOne({"Age": "37"})
null
> db.heartbeat.findOne({"Sex": "0"})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("616d93fdadc1f5af9f25aeb7"),
        "Age" : "41",
        "Sex" : "0",
        "ChestPainType" : "1",
        "RestingBP" : "130",
        "Cholesterol" : "204",
        "FastingBloodSugar" : "0",
        "RestingECG" : "0",
        "MaxHeartRate" : "172",
        "ExerciseInducedAngina" : "0",
        "STDepression" : "1.4",
        "STlope" : "2",
        "ca" : "0",
        "thal" : "2",
        "target" : "1"
}
```

Comment: @turivishal you can see in the image i have tried both query with `{"Age": 37}` and `{"Age": "37"}`, both returns null

Comment: It should work, not sure but there is some issue in connection, is this replicaset? what is the connection string sample.

Comment: Did you try to run in directly in `mongo` shell?